# Как сравнить даты в MS Access?

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, ms-access, oledb

В таблице столбцы `date_in` и `date_out` в виде "14.10.19"
Столбцы типа `string`

В программе получаю период, например, с "14.10.19" по "01.11.19"
Нужно выбрать строки, у которых `date_in` и `date_out` укладываются в выбранный интервал или если указана одна граница. Например, `date_in` то выбрать все, которые после этой даты

Пробовал

```
WHERE Date(date_in)>Date("14.10.19")  
WHERE date_in>"14/10/19"
```

получаю строки у которых день месяца больше указанного, месяц и год игнорируются
можно написать и

```
DateTime dt=Convert.ToDateTime(datetime);
WHERE DAY(date_in)>dt.Day and MONTH(date_in)
```

и т.д. Но хотелось бы покороче.

Comment: _Всегда_ указывайте используемую СУБД. Какой тип у `date_in` и `date_out`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в заголовке OleDB.  `date_in` и `date_out` в виде "14.10.19" т.е. строки

Comment: OleDb - это способ доступа к _разным_ БД. А какая _именно_ используется?

Comment: Какой _тип_ у этих колонок? `varchar`, `nchar`, `datetime`, `smalldatetime`, etc? Не в коде C#, а в БД?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ms access база. в конструкторе указано "Короткий текст" длиной 255

Comment: Ох, я плохо знаю Access, надеялся, что кто-то поможет. Но все заняты... Во-первых, нужно тип данных в БД сменить. Вместо "Короткий текст" использовать "Дата" или другой подходящий тип (повторю, я не знаю Access, какие там типы есть). После этого сравнение дат будет простым и удобным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас явно неверно спроектирована база данных. Выбор по диапазону дат из поля типа "строка" корректно невозможен без дополнительных преобразований. Для того, что бы избежать подобного, необходимо тип полей `date_in` и `date_out` изменить на "Дата и время" (для MS Access) через конструктор таблиц.

После этого запрос на выборку по диапазону дат будет иметь достаточно короткий и очевидный вид:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE date_in BETWEEN #10/14/2019# AND #11/1/2019#;
```

**Хочу отдельно обратить внимание на формат констант типа дата в запросе**: для MS Access они должны быть строго в формате USA: `#M/D/YYYY#`, то есть, даты и месяц указываются без предстоящего нуля (не `01-31` и `01-12`, а `1-31` и `1-12`), и месяц указывается перед датой. Разделитель - строго слеш `/`. Дата оборачивается с двух сторон в решетки `#`.